# Calling variables from C++ class to Objective C class

Tags: c++, objective-c, objective-c++, openframeworks

I am creating an instance of an Objective C class from a C++ instance. The problem is that when trying to get the values of some vars (in the obj c instance) I always get 0. Some NSLogs are also ignored!:

Objective C class:
InAppPurchaseManager.h

```
@interface InAppPurchaseManager : NSObject <SKProductsRequestDelegate, SKPaymentTransactionObserver>{
    SKProduct *proUpgradeProduct;
    SKProductsRequest *productsRequest;
@public
    int finishedPurchaseProcess;
}
- (int)hasFinishedPurchaseProcess;
- (void)purchase;
@end
```

InAppPurchaseManager.m

```
@implementation InAppPurchaseManager
- (void)purchase{
    finishedPurchaseProcess=1;
}
- (int)hasFinishedPurchaseProcess{
    NSLog(@"STORE: HELLO THERE");   
    return finishedPurchaseProcess;
}
```

testApp.h
    class testApp : public ofxiPhoneApp {
        public:
        void goToStoreFromMenu();
        void checkPurchase();
        InAppPurchaseManager * theStore;
    }

testApp.mm

```
// First I call ghis function
void testApp::goToStoreFromMenu(){  
    InAppPurchaseManager* theStore = [[InAppPurchaseManager alloc] init];
    [theStore purchase];
}

// And then this function
void testApp::checkPurchase(){  
    cout << "Finished? " << [theStore hasFinishedPurchaseProcess] << "\n";
}
```

and the result is always **Finished? 0**, even if I set it to 1 in **purchase**. Also the **NSLog(@"STORE: HELLO THERE");** is ignored

I don't understand what's going on

Comment: did you try debug your app? does it reach NSLog(...) when debugged ?

Comment: Have you tried removing the `InAppPurchaseManager*` in `testApp::goToStoreFromMenu`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `goToStoreFromMenu`, you declare a new local variable named `theStore`. In `checkPurchase`, you refer to some *other* variable with the same name. The `goToStoreFromMenu` function initializes the local variable, which goes out of scope at the end of the function. You need to initialize the same variable that you'll eventually refer to in `checkPurchase`.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to include `testApp.h`, where `theStore` is declared. I edited the question accordingly. Thanks

Comment: You still appear to be declaring an additional, separate variable called 'theStore', in testApp::goToStoreFromMenu.

Comment: oh! Now I understand! You are right, it should be `theStore = [[InAppPurchaseManager alloc] init];` . Thanks!